# Magic Method in PHP for triggering method when a declared property is set?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

I have a class with declared properties.  The whole point of the class and it's extensions is that I need them to always be available, even if null, on a different object. So it looks like:

```
class Wrapper {

     public $a = "";
     public $b = "";
     public $c = "";

    public function Wrapper() {

        $this -> wrapped = new Wrapped();

        foreach($this as $key => $val) {
              if($key != 'wrapped') {
                 $this -> wrapped -> $key = $val;
              }
        }

    }
}
```

But after instantiating the object, I want to be able to overwrite the declared values directly, so:

```
 $wrap_test = new Wrapper();
 $wrap_test -> a = 12;
```

So rather than writing a method or using `$wrap_test -> wrapped -> a -> 12`, I was looking for an equivalent to __set() that would call a method whenever any property is set.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your properties are declared `public`, there's no "event" or other method you can hook into. The properties can simply be changed directly by anybody.

Declare your properties as `protected` or `private` so they cannot be changed directly from outside the class, then implement the `__get` and `__set` methods so you are able to access the properties as if they were `public`. In the `__set` method, do whatever you need to do when the property changes.

Comment: Perfect.  Now the only problem is when I set a property from within the class itself.  I think I have an idea for that, though...

Comment: Here's what I came up with (this avoids static variables getting in there):  `     $og_properties = array_keys(array_intersect(get_class_vars(get_class($this)), get_object_vars($this)));
      
     if(!in_array($name, $og_properties)) {
      $this -> $name = $value;
     } else  {`